# Bringing many sensors together in one ACtivity

Tags: android, class

I am creating an app that will use many different sensors.  Each sensor will have its own class as each sensor will record values direct to an internal database.

One activity ActivityRecord will have a button which executes activation of the responsible methods in the Sensor Classes.

```
    RecordButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Start/Stop Recording
            if (!isRecording) {
                startRecording();

                RecordButton.setText("Stop Recording");
            } else {

                stopRecording();
                RecordButton.setText("Start Recording");
            }

        }

    });

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private void startRecording() {

    isRecording = true;

    //Light Sensor stuff here

    }
```

For now I have a LightSensor.java Class where the final output is as so:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    lightLux = event.values[0]; //Final output of this sensor.
    Lux = String.valueOf(lightLux);
    Log.d("LightSensor", Lux);

    TextView tvLightSensorLux = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLightSensorLux);
    tvLightSensorLux.setText(Lux);

}
```

lightLux being the float output or Lux the String output.  So in the FragmentRecord.java I want to show the output of LightSensor lightLux or setText of Lux to a tv.

QUESTION:  How do I get the values of lightLux and Lux from LightSensor.java to FragmentRecord.java?  This will apply to every other sensor that I create in the future also.

I have imported *.LightSensor already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Sensor classes should notify the activity when there's something to update.

Option 1 - define an interface like so:

```
interface OnSensorChanges {
    void onSensorChanged(int sensorId, double sensorValue);
}
```

Implement it in your activity and pass it to each of your sensors. The sensors will call the method on the interface, and your activity will update the UI.

Of course, if not all sensors send a number (some send coordinates), you should probably wrap the value in a `Bundle` (since a single interface is better than multiple interfaces IMO).

Option 2 - If you want a more 'Android-like' solution:

Implement the sensor listeners in a service, and send broadcasts to report sensor changes. You'd better use the [`LocalBroadcastManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) to make things a bit leaner. Just note the `LocalBroadcastManager` is part of the support library.

Comment: cool.  SO I understand that in each *Sensor.java add or create an interface.  In the consolidated View where all sensor outputs shall be displayed, that View should talk connect to each individual interface.  While each Sensor.interface is updating itself upon change, it is sending an update to the UI of the consolidated view (ActivityRecord) ?

Comment: Actually rereading your hint again, I think I understood it backwards.  In ActivityRecord, I should put interface OnSensorChanges.  There should also be a reference to that method in each sensor.  So basically as each *Sensor.java updates itself it will send those updates to that interface for a UI update?

Comment: One more question:  Since ActivityRecorder will be the layout that shows the results from the sensors like graphs and numbers and stuff, do you think that ActivityRecorder should be the Receiver Class listening for all sensors? Or is it better to create a separate Receiver.java that will accept all broadcasts and then get those updates from Receiver to Recorder?  Or is that exactly the same problem I am already in?

Comment: I wouldn't create a separate receiver object, because you'll have to update the activity from it, and add another interface between them.  Except maybe if the receiver is a fragment that handles its own UI.